# Uso de la función array_filter en una petición GET

Tags: php, json, http-get

Estoy teniendo bastantes problemas con una petición `GET` formada por dos parámetros que quiero filtrar:

```
$app->get('/api/v1/providerD/{destino}/{peso}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

   $em = getEntityManager();
   $destino = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByDestino($args['destino']);
   $peso = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByPeso($args['peso']);

     $provider_filtrado = array_filter($destino, function ($dato) {
        return $dato->peso == $peso;    
    });

    return $response->withJson($provider_filtrado);
});
```

Si en lugar de `return $dato->peso == $peso;` escribo `return $dato->peso == 3;` por ejemplo, obtengo el resultado correcto.
El problema está en que al utilizar la variable `$peso` obtengo el error `Undefined variable: peso` ya que está definido fuera del `array_filter`. Si lo defino dentro de `array_filter`no puedo obtener el peso que me pasan por parámetro ya que aparece el error: `Undefined variable: args`.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconozco la versión de PHP con la que trabajas, pero en las ultimas versiones las [funciones anónimas](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php) aceptan el constructor de lenguaje `use` para heredar variables:

```
$app->get('/api/v1/providerD/{destino}/{peso}', function ($request, $response, $args) {

   $em = getEntityManager();
   $destino = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByDestino($args['destino']);
   $peso = $em->getRepository(Transporte::class)->findByPeso($args['peso']);

     $provider_filtrado = array_filter($destino, function ($dato) use ($peso) {
        return $dato->peso == $peso;    
    });

    return $response->withJson($provider_filtrado);
});
```

Si observas, lo que debes reemplazar es:

```
$provider_filtrado = array_filter($destino, function ($dato) {
        return $dato->peso == $peso;    
    });
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
$provider_filtrado = array_filter($destino, function ($dato) use ($peso) {
        return $dato->peso == $peso;    
    });
```